# REST/RPC API asyn calls to micro services

Tags: node.js, django, python-2.7, rabbitmq, tornado

I am working on many micro services for the users request. Any library do asyn call to many other services like billing, recommendation
and do the check and response back.

Ex:

call some api

```
get(request):

  // call two services async
  billing = billingService(user_id)  //service end point 1
  recommendation = recommendation_service(user_id)  //service end point 2

  // we will have results from those two services

  //check conditions response to user  
  if billing == OK:
       response (recommendation)  // response
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use promise to resolve the above issue.

```
billing = billingService(user_id).then(results => {
//Here in the results variable the output of billing service method will be stored if billing service method returns a promise.
recommendation = recommendation_service(user_id)})
```

Promise is the most efficient way to address asynchronous calls in javascript.

If you are specifically searcing for any library you can use 'q' library of node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ES7's async/await. It'll be easier to write and your code will look a lot cleaner too.

Once you get it to work, your code will look something like:

```
const billing = await billingService(user_id)
const recommendation = await recommendation_service(user_id)
```

I'd recommend learning Promises too (afterall they've been successfully saving people from callback hell) to unmistify async/await (as your billingService and recommendation_service would eventually need to be async functions before they can be awaited)

Hope this helps!